# The counter doesn't count all the different vowels

Tags: c++

The program is supposed to take a string as input and count the number of vowels but also which exact vowels they are. For some reason it seems to be able to count As but not other vowels.

```
int main()
{
std::string inp;
int counter = 0;
int a = 0, i = 0, e = 0, o = 0, u = 0;
std::cout << "Enter the string: ";
std::cin >> inp;
for (int i = 0; i < inp.length(); i++)
{
    switch(inp[i])
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            counter++;
            a++;
            break;
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            counter++;
            e++;
            break;
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
            counter++;
            i++;
            break;
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            counter++;
            u++;
            break;
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            counter++;
            o++;
            break;
    }
} 
std::cout << "There were " << counter << " vowels in total." << std::endl;
std::cout << "There were " << a << " As, " << i << " Is, " << o << " Os, " << u << " Us, and " << e << " Es." << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some specific input, what is the expected and actual output (please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/))? And have you tried to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program?

Comment: Which encoding are you using in your terminal?

Comment: Regarding debugging, I also recommend you add a `default` case to your `switch` statement, as it will make it easier to debug.

Comment: You have 2 variables `i` counter and loop.

Comment: Lastly, what happens in the case of `'i'` and `'I'`? How many variables named `i` do you have?

Comment: Try adding `-Wshadow` to your compile command

Comment: Enter the string: Instruction
There were 3 vowels in total.
There were 0 As, 0 Is, 0 Os, 1 Us, and 0 Es.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop variable `i` is hiding the `i` in the outer scope. That results in *i*s not being counted correctly and in skipping characters (as every time you meet an `'i'` you increment `i` the loop variable).

Change the loop variable name to something else.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem and I understand the mistake now.